# lodash: primary sort by a key and secondary sort by another key

Tags: ecmascript-6, lodash

I have data in the below format. I am currently using orderBy by to sort by specific "number" key. I am looking for a way to secondary by another key "name".

```
[
{
  "number": "123",
  "name": "a"
},
{
  "number": "123",
  "name": "b"
},
{
  "number": "123",
  "name": "br"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [orderBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#orderBy):

```js
const arr = [
  {number: 123, name: "b"},
  {number: 123, name: "a"},
  {number: 122, name: "br"},
  {number: 124, name: "bR"},
  {number: 124, name: "Br"}
];

console.log(
  _.orderBy(arr, e => [e.number, e.name.toLowerCase() /* case insensitively */])
);

const arr2 = [
  {number: 121, name: "c"},
  {number: 122, name: "b"},
  {number: 123, name: "a"}
];

console.log(
  _.orderBy(arr2, e => e.number /* descending */, 'desc')
);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/lodash/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just wondering, is there a way to specify asc and desc for these columns and also case insensitive for the fields.

Comment: Case insensitive is easy (`e => [..., e.name.toLowerCase()]`), descending is harder, depends on: what range can your numbers  take?

Comment: I am wondering will this work [..., e.name.toLowerCase()], ['asc', 'desc']) so that it will sort by first numbers ascending and name descending.

Comment: I don't think so, but added a solution to my answer using MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. Not really great if numbers can be floating point though

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have code written in this format and it's not working as expected. I am using kendo grid in my app. I am primary sorting based on the column that the user has clicked and secondary sort by always extension.  I get the primary sort column name and dir from this.sort[0]. there could be cases where primary sort and secondary sort column can be the same, if the user clicks on extension column. I am wondering the issue might be because of that.     this.phonesData = sortBy(this.phonesData, [this.sort[0].field, 'extension'], [this.sort[0].dir, 'asc']);

Comment: @indra257 But `sortBy()` only accepts 1 Array of selectors, in your comment you pass 2 arrays

Comment: I am trying to sort data by one column and if any values are equal, it should secondary sort by another column specified

Comment: `sortBy()` doesn't support directions in that way.

Comment: You need `orderBy()` then: `this.phonesData = _.orderBy(this.phonesData, [this.sort[0].field, 'extension'], [this.sort[0].dir, 'asc])`